# jQuery anythingSlider - make the first slide last twice as long

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [anythingSlider](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/) by Chris Coyier.

Basically it makes list-items slide in from the left after a specified time.

I'd like to tweak the code, so that the first `<li>` is visible for twice as long as the others.

E.g. If the slides are visible for 7 seconds, the first slide needs to be visible for 14 seconds.

Any ideas?

Comment: just btw. anythingSlider doesn't seem to work in Opera 10.10 (at least for me). You should verify if it is crossbrowser usable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be easy enough

```
var timeVisible = 7000;
$('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider({
    autoPlay: true,
    startStopped: true,
    delay: timeVisible ,
    ...
});

setTimeout(function() {
    $("div.anythingSlider a#start-stop").trigger("click");
}, timeVisible);
```

Comment: This would be in the head of the page the slider is on, rather than editing the anythingSlider code it's self?? Is that true?

Comment: Yes, exactly. No fiddling with anythingSlider source code needed. You just start the slider stopped and then programmatically start it after a certain amount of time via a `setTimeout`function. This way you can even show the first slide as long as you want

Comment: This is actually more of a fiddling, because it breaks the auto-start functionality and thereby relies on user interaction (i.e. click). Don't blame ya. This is alright, when that's it what the OP was searching for.

Comment: You are totally wrong, auto-start functionality is not broken. Had you tried it you would have seen that no user interaction at all is required. jQuery starts the autoPlay after the defined period. The user doesn't need to click with the mouse or do anything at all.

Comment: I think here is a misunderstanding. I said auto-start. I never claimed autoPlay wouldn't work.
Though one could fire the timer on the document ready event, which then would basically auto-start.

Comment: I still can't grasp what your problem is. Check this demo page and tell me how it doesn't do what Jonny Haynes requested http://jsbin.com/usuti First image is shown 6 seconds, every other image is shown only 3 seconds. No user interaction required not even to start the slider

Comment: langsam dämmerts ;) I does indeed work very good. Sorry for causing trouble! You may edit your post so I can give it a thumbs up instead!

Comment: offtopic: something is wrong with stackoverflow. The points did show two for me and out of curiosity I clicked again on the up arrow and it switched back to 1 and remains the same. just saying...

Comment: Clicking the uparrow a second time "undos" your vote. But you should be able to click a third time to vote up again

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `startStop` function to this (notice `var extraTime`):

```
        // Handles stopping and playing the slideshow
    // Pass startStop(false) to stop and startStop(true) to play
    base.startStop = function(playing){
        if(playing !== true) playing = false; // Default if not supplied is false

        // Update variable
        base.playing = playing;

        // Toggle playing and text
        if(base.options.autoPlay) base.$startStop.toggleClass("playing", playing).html( playing ? base.options.stopText : base.options.startText );

        var extraTime = 0;
        if(base.currentPage == 1){
            extraTime = base.options.delay;
        }

        if(playing){
            base.clearTimer(); // Just in case this was triggered twice in a row
            base.timer = window.setInterval(function(){
                base.goForward(true);
            }, base.options.delay + extraTime);
        } else {
            base.clearTimer();
        };
    };
```

This is in line 223 of `jquery.anythingslider.js`.

Answer (score 0):

> anythingSlider doesn't seem to work in Opera 10.10 (at least for me).

.anythingSlider .wrapper ul             { width: 99999px;
--->
.anythingSlider .wrapper ul             { width: 9999px;